# How can I search for malicious cron jobs?

Tags: cron

I have an account at WebFaction, and multiple sites that have been hacked, now multiple times, over the past month. Most of these are WordPress installs.

Every time this happens I change all passwords -- user, site access, databases, etc. -- update WordPress, and look for cron jobs in the WordPress installs.

I'm pretty confident that I know how to change a password (and generate secure passwords). If there's a gap in my (low level of) knowledge, it's cron jobs and whether or not I might be missing something in working through all of this in terms of a "back door" being left open.

Is there an automated way I can search for these? If I have to manually open every single one of these hundreds and hundreds of compromised PHP files, is there a certain text string or something I can search for that will help me find (and understand) what these are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've been hacked there's only two secure ways: Reinstall completely from known good installation sources or restore a backup that you know for sure was taken before the intrusion.

Once an attacker has gained access to a system, there are so many ways to hide malicious code that it is impossible to go through it all and be sure nothing is left.